# Is there a way to bind properties together?

Tags: c#, vb.net, mvvm

I've recently needed to synchronize values from a higher up view model (bound to a custom tab content control) to the base one (bound to the host view) for the CanExecute delegate in the host view to use. The base model has the instance of the top one, among others.

The only thing that I can think of for it to know when a value changes higher up is to subscribe to the PropertyChanged event. But, that seems excessive considering how many times that event would get fired for all of the other properties. It also doesn't feel right for MVVM (but I may be wrong).

Right now, I'm setting it all in a central method in the manager class where the magic happens to make sure the values match up:

```vb
     If setDealable Then multilegViewModel.IsDealable = isDealable

     multilegViewModel.IsIndicative = (Not isDealable)

     ' [...]

     tktViewModel.IsCommandOtherEnabled = (Not isDealable)
     tktViewModel.IsCommandBuyEnabled = multilegViewModel.IsBuyButtonEnabled
     tktViewModel.IsCommandSellEnabled = multilegViewModel.IsSellButtonEnabled

     tktViewModel.IsDealable = isDealable
     tktViewModel.IsIndicative = (Not isDealable)

     ' [...]
```

But, smaller sets of the "multilegViewModel" properties are being set elsewhere, so I have to find them all and add the copy over. The risk is having another developer leave out such a pairing somewhere.

**So, does anyone have ideas other than one view model subscribing to the other to ensure that the values always get set?**

*Note: The dual language tags are on purpose. It's a mixed language solution, such as the manager being VB.NET, but the models are C#, so I accept suggestions in either one.*

UPDATE: I've changed my approach and greatly simplified it, so my initial reason for needing this is no longer valid. But, I may have an edge case or two that could still benefit from this.